# Create a readonly text field but without a textfield border

Tags: html, css, textfield

Im trying to create a text field which is readonly but it should not look like a text field.

The normal readonly text field is

```
Your name is [ SAM ]
```

but I want it like

```
Your name is SAM
```

That is it should look like the continuation of the sentence and can still act as a text field on to which we can show value (here SAM).
Any way to do that?

Comment: You can do it by css.

Comment: or html5 content-editable http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What your looking for is this:

### HTML:

```
Your name is <input type="text" value="SAM" readonly="readonly" />
```

### CSS:

```
input {
    border: 0;
}
```

You can set the input field to `readonly` in the HTML, this will make it so you cannot edit the field. Then you want to get rid of the border to so it makes it look like its apart of the text. Then customise it as you see fit.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/csj5W/)

## Update:

If the input is in a div/span you can just the inputs within that `div`/`span` like so:

### HTML:

```
<span class="test">Your name is <input type="text" value="SAM" readonly="readonly" /></span>
```

### CSS:

```
.test input {
    border: 0;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/csj5W/1/)

Comment: I want just that input to be border less,i tried making a class and added to this input but its default design is coming

Comment: What is it wrapped in? Just take the `div` class or id and put it in front. Or for that matter you could just give the input a class of its own and use that.

Comment: when I remove the readonly its using my css class,but when readonly is added its losingits css property

Comment: In your example you wasnt setting the class. Class is `.`. You was just setting `x`. Change the CSS to `.x` instead of `x` and it will fix it. [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xMG48/5/)

Comment: please check this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825486/cannot-apply-css-to-read-only-html-field-in-jquery-mobile

Comment: I tried putting as per your answer update but still only the default style for text field is coming

Answer (score 8):

to style all readonly textboxes apply following CSS rule

```
input[readonly="readonly"] {
      border:0px;
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer as only the "readonly" inputs are affected.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by css. **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/xMG48/3/)**

```
<style>
*
{
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 13px;
}
input
{
    background-color:transparent;
    border:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
</style>
this is the <input type='text' value='textbox' readonly >
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the border, outline and background to `none` and you'll get the desired effect.

```
input[disabled] {
    background:none;            
    border:none;
    outline:none;
}
```

It would still take the default min-width though, so you might have to set the width to a smaller value.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/VpfZR/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="text"]:focus { border: none; outline: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the Border to 0px and the background to transparent, This should be work.

In CSS file:

```
*
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
input[type="text"]
{
    border:0px solid red;
    background: none;
}
```

In HTML file:

```
Hello <input type="text" value="John">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, why don't you use `CSS` for this?

Add:

`input[type="text"] { border: none; }`

Also an option: adding background transparancy as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" value = "Your Name is SAM" readonly= "true" style ="border: none" name="name"/>
```